# Authentication for class based views in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

```
class AdminView(generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'is_active']
    template_name = 'users/admin.html'

class AdminUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['is_active']
    template_name = 'users/user_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:admin')
```

There are two views in django which I have created and I want them to be accessed only when the admin/staff logins. How do I go about it?

Comment: I tried using method_decorator but how to create a custom decorator to be passed inside it? Like login_required is already there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) and [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) mixins, and specify as condition that the user should be an `is_superuser`. Since you need these twice, we can make first a composite mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class AdminStaffRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_staff
```

Next you can add the mixin to your class-based views:

```
class AdminView(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'is_active']
    template_name = 'users/admin.html'

class AdminUpdateView(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['is_active']
    template_name = 'users/user_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:admin')
```

Comment: So LoginRequiredMixin is inherited so that one can set the login_url if the test in UserPassesTestMixin is not passed, right?

Comment: @AmanSharma: indeed, this will also first check if the user is logged in (since techhnically it is for example possible that your know the user, but that user is not logged in, if you "change" the login procedure).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get 'django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied' when I try your method. However, the solution works! How to get rid of the error?

Comment: @abicrazieeee: you can set the `raise_exception` attribute to `raise_exception = False`. See https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.contrib.auth.mixins/UserPassesTestMixin/ how the mixin is implemented.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Setting `raise_exception = False` in my class based view doesn't work. I had to implement a `handle_no_permission` method in my class and return a custom HTTP response. I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class AdminView(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'is_active']
    template_name = 'users/admin.html'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff or self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Comment: I get 'django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied' when I try your method. However, the solution works! How to get rid of the error?

Comment: @abicrazieeee not sure, probably user is not staff or superuser?

Comment: The user is a superuser.  I had to implement a handle_no_permission method in my class and return a custom HTTP response to get rid of the error tho.

Answer (score 2):

Use decorators, with @login_required you can tell this views will be only accesseed when user os logged in, you can pass parameters to it too or create one your own to validate if the logged user on the request can see or no your view

With Login Required

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
class AdminView(generic.ListView):
    ...

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
class AdminUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

With Permission

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('user.is_staff')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the LoginRequiredMixin, you still can. And it is much simpler. Just extend the LoginRequiredMixin in all you classes so that they are like this.

```
class AdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'is_active']
    template_name = 'users/admin.html'

class AdminUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['is_active']
    template_name = 'users/user_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:admin')
```

This ensures that the user is already logged in before allowing any operations. Then, check if the user is an admin by adding the following code to each of the classes;

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Your code should now look like this:

```
class AdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'is_active']
    template_name = 'users/admin.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class AdminUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['is_active']
    template_name = 'users/user_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:admin')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsAdminUser` permission by rest framework

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class AdminView(generic.ListView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, )
    ...
```